# Stop button from overflowing

Tags: html, css

Image of overflowing button:

[image]

I have section-b-home class that has 2 buttons and I'm fairly new to CSS and I cant seem to stop the button from overflowing a section inside the grid element.

Is there any way I can fix the button inside the parent element?

Can you also please check other aspects of my code and if there are issues that needs fixing?

my CSS and HTML:

```css
    html {
    font-family: Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(193, 200, 228, 1) 18%, rgba(132, 222, 235, 1) 50%, rgba(130, 220, 235, 1) 52%, rgba(90, 185, 234, 1) 86%);
    font-size: 62.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

span {
    font-size: 0.7rem;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    display: block;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.5;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 0.65fr 9fr 1.45fr;
}

.section-wrapper-home {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

section {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #666;
    text-align: center;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #333;
}

.section-a-home {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}

.section-a-home span {
    font-size: 7rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    color: rgba(16, 20, 24, 0.904);
}

.section-b-home {
    grid-column: 4;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.section-c-home {
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.section-d-home {
    grid-column: 6;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.section-e-home {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.section-f-home {
    grid-column: 4/7;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.section-g-home {
    grid-column: 1/3;
    grid-row: 4;
}

.section-h-home {
    grid-column: 3/5;
    grid-row: 4;
}

.section-i-home {
    grid-column: 5/7;
    grid-row: 4;
}

.test {
    height: 100%;
}

.test .btn {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer-wrapper {
    border-top: 1px solid #555;
}

.header-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

.header-theme i {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.header-date {
    justify-self: flex-start;
}

.header-title {
    justify-self: center;
}

.header-theme {
    justify-self: end;
}

.footer-nav {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer-nav button {
    height: 90%;
    width: 95%;
}

.fas {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
      <header class="header-wrapper">
          <nav class="header-nav">
              <div class="header-date">
                  <span>12-12-2021</span><br /> <span>04:05:06 AM</span>
              </div>
              <div class="header-title">
                  <h1>Room Name</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="header-theme">
                  <i class="fas fa-sun" id="theme-light"></i>
                  <i class="fas fa-moon" id="theme-dark"></i>
              </div>
          </nav>
      </header>

      <main class="main-wrapper">
          <div class="section-wrapper-home">
              <section class="section section-a-home">
                  <h2>Room Temperature</h2>
                  <span>20.05&#176;C</span>
              </section>
              <section class="section section-b-home">
                  <h2>Climate Control</h2>
                  <div class="test">
                      <button class="btn">On</button>
                      <button class="btn">Off</button>
                  </div>
              </section>
              <section class="section section-c-home"></section>
              <section class="section section-d-home"></section>
              <section class="section section-e-home"></section>
              <section class="section section-f-home"></section>
              <section class="section section-g-home"></section>
              <section class="section section-h-home"></section>
              <section class="section section-i-home"></section>
          </div>
      </main>

      <footer class="footer-wrapper">
          <nav class="footer-nav">
              <button><i class="fas fa-home" id="nav-home"></i></button>
              <button><i class="fas fa-lightbulb" id="nav-light"></i></button>
              <button><i class="fas fa-window-maximize" id="nav-curtain"></i></button>
              <button><i class="fas fa-music" id="nav-audio"></i></button>
              <button><i class="fas fa-thermometer-half" id="nav-climate"></i></button>
          </nav>

      </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, add `overflow: hidden;` in the `test` class.
Example:

```css
.section-b-home .test {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```